# correct place to call process.exit() in promise chain

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Having problems understanding interaction of node processes and promise chains:

```
doSomethingAsync()
.then()
.then()
.catch()
.finally();
```

The finally was introduced to close db connections opened inside doSomethingAsync().

**Question**: In which block does a `process.exit(1)` on error properly belong?

- In the `.catch()`, since that's where errors will go, or
- In the `.finally()` since it is the last thing that should happen? (But if there is an error and `catch()` is triggered, do the connections get released)?
- nowhere, because node already knows the program failed?

Comment: Why would you catch the error at all if the plan is to stop the application when an error occurs? Why not let the process naturally terminate with the uncaught exception?

Comment: @James Likely because a process isn't terminated by uncaught rejection by default.

Comment: @estus `await` the promise? Point I'm making is if the goal is to let the process stop on an error then do that, it's safer to let it naturally terminate than catching & manually terminating. I understand perhaps the OP isn't aware of how to do this hence why I asked the question.

Comment: @James I got the impression node was always bleating about uncaught exceptions, and how in future they will not be handled... or somesuch? I see what you're saying though - it can be good to let a thing just fail hopelessly. thx for the input

Comment: @yen uncaught exceptions are not handled by default, they need to be caught via `uncaughtException` event. As estus has pointed out, unhandled promise rejections currently _are_ handled (they'll currently just log a message to the console). I believe there are plans down the line to change this behaviour to be the same as uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to have the application terminate when an error occurs then I wouldn't catch the exception at all

```
async function doSomething() {
  try {
    const result = await doSomethingAsync();
    // do something with result  
  } finally {
    // do cleanup
  }
}
```

Using `async` / `await` syntax will allow the Promise to throw the error and the uncaught exception would terminate the application. The `finally` block will run regardless of whether an error was thrown or not.

Comment: yeah, I reckon you're right. then().then().finally(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case `process.exit(1)` belongs in `finally()`, because there are database connections to be closed. You would probably want to close them first and then do `process.exit(1)`.

If there was no logic to be performed, I would exit the process in `catch()`.

Comment: but how would finally() "know" that we ever had an error and went through catch()? Also there might not have been an error, in which case finally would not return exit code 1?

Comment: you could set an `exitCodem = 1` variable in the catch and then use that in the finally: `process.exit(exitCode)`.